# How do I deploy a war file to weblogic using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, weblogic12c

I have the following configuration setup to deploy a war file to Weblogic.

```
buildscript{
  configurations {
    weblogic
  }

  dependencies {
    weblogic project.file('./libs/wlfullclient.jar') // line 15
  }
}
```

But, when I try to execute the build script, I get the error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\workspace\somedir\inetsys\someproj\build.gradle' line: 15
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'someproj'.

  > Could not find method weblogic() for arguments [C:\workspace\somdir\inetsys\someproj\libs\wlfullclient.jar] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1846d05.

Can you please help?

Comment: As the answerer indicates, using a plugin designed to deploy to weblogic is a better idea.  If any part of this existing build script is still relevant, you should read the gradle user guide to understand how to specify buildscript dependencies. You don't define or use configurations in the buildscript block.